# Replace string char but keep the case type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code that when user type some value in upper and lower case I mark the value as bold,this following code is working.

```
var typedVal = oAcF._sTypedChars.toLowerCase();
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(typedVal, "<b>" + typedVal + "</b>");
```

here I got the value and put it to lower case since I want to handle cases when user type with upper case

```
var typedVal = oAcF._sTypedChars.toLowerCase();
```

here I take the value can be e.g aa and find it in the inner html and add to it bold.

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(typedVal, "<b>" + typedVal + "</b>")
```

the problem is that if I have in the innerHTML  e.g. AA it will not work since the value is in upper case,how can I overcome it?

I cannot use the following since I want to keep the value with the original case so in this example upper case...

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(typedVal, "<b>" + typedVal + "</b>")
```

Comment: `var re = new RegExp(typedVal, "ig");`

Comment: @Mouser-Thanks but not sure the I got it...

Comment: To clarify, if `typedval` is `"AAA"`, you want to match `"aaa"`, `"AaA"` regardless of case, but return the found string with the same case with which it was found?

Comment: @DavidThomas-correct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it a bit difficult to exactly comprehend your question. I think you want this:

```
 var typedVal = oAcF._sTypedChars.toLowerCase();
 var re = new RegExp("("+typedVal.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')+")", "ig");  
 element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Use the `i`  or ignore case while searching the string, So `aaa` will also find `aAa`, while keeping it *uppercase*.

The `g` will perform this globally, or simply said to every instance it can find.

When you use a variable in replace as the search string, you cannot apply the `ignore case` and `global` flag, so you need to use the `RegExp` constructor.

`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` is used to escape characters that would otherwise break the regexp.

Inspired by the other post and your own comment I too realize that you need to use a capture group `$#`. Those are created when you use parenthesis around a regex part. We have only one capture group so identify it with `$1`.

In practice:

```js
function changeInput(element)
{
     var typedVal = document.querySelector("input").value.toLowerCase();
     var re = new RegExp("("+typedVal.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')+")", "ig");  
     element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", changeInput.bind(window, document.querySelector("div")), false);
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dignissim risus quis lorem scelerisque, in varius felis consectetur. Quisque dignissim leo eros, nec accumsan velit sodales id. Nullam laoreet lectus sit amet felis dignissim, eu fermentum tortor gravida. Praesent aliquet auctor purus, a bibendum nisl convallis et. Mauris fermentum purus mauris, vitae porttitor dolor scelerisque at. Aenean arcu leo, semper eu elementum sed, rutrum a eros. Vivamus a ante urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent lorem sapien, pretium et elementum vitae, maximus finibus ligula. Morbi imperdiet venenatis nisi eget eleifend. In ornare odio ante, ac congue velit blandit non. Sed pulvinar lorem ac ex tristique cursus at ut eros. Sed rutrum tristique turpis, in facilisis dui gravida lobortis. </div>

<input placeholder="type some input here" />
<button>Click to highlight the input</button>
```

Comment: You probably should escape potential regex special characters within `typedVal`. Moreover, your code will replace by `typedVal` which has been `toLowerCase`'d. Maybe you should add capturing parenthesis to prevent case from changing.

Comment: @Ninetainedo thanks, was looking in my code libraries for the escape sequence :-) found it.

Comment: @Mouser-Thanks Ive check it but the problem is that the original value change to the typed value,for example I type "in" and in the list I've INDEX now it replace it to inDEX (the in in bold),how can i avoid it...

Comment: @Mark see updated, however the answers are starting to be very similar now.

Comment: As regards your last point, yes. Up-voted for that very reason (it seems silly to not up-vote a similar answer, unless I secretly think my own isn't good enough...)

Comment: @DavidThomas I share your opinion, your contains more info for newbies though, very elaborate, nice!

Comment: Thanks, there's some (hopefully) useful information in there; congratulations on your accept! :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use a capturing group, which in this case requires you to use the `new RegExp()` constructor:

```
var reg = new RegExp('(' + typedval + ')', 'i');
```

And, in the replace call, using a reference to that captured group (in this case either `$1`, the first group, or `$&`, the entire group):

```
replace(reg, "<b>$1</b>");
```

or:

```
replace(reg, "<b>$&</b>");
```

A simple demo (though a little abstracted from your own presented code) using the `$1` approach:

```js
var typedval = "AAA",
  // constructing a regular expression, via the RegExp constructor,
  // effectively concatenating strings to give (in this instance):
  // new RegExp('(AAA)', 'ig')
  // the '(AAA)' is the match we're looking for,
  // the 'ig' are the flags (i: case-insensitive, g: global):
  reg = new RegExp('(' + typedval + ')', 'ig'),
  // finding all the <li> elements on the page:
  lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// using Array methods to iterate over the <li> elements:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(lis, function(li) {
  // updating the innerHTML, using the created regular expression
  // with the String.prototype.replace() method:
  li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replace(reg, "<b>$1</b>");
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>AaA</li>
  <li>aAA</li>
  <li>AAa</li>
</ul>
```

And using the `$&` approach:

```js
var typedval = "AAA",
  reg = new RegExp('(' + typedval + ')', 'ig'),
  lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(lis, function(li) {
  li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML.replace(reg, "<b>$&</b>");
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>AaA</li>
  <li>aAA</li>
  <li>AAa</li>
</ul>
```

Further to the comments you've left on another answer, where it seems that if the entered string is `"in"` you don't want to match `"index"` or `"intermittent"`, you can use word-boundaries (`\\b`, double-escaped because we're using string-concatenation wherein the `\` character is an escape character, which we need to escape) in the `RegExp()` constructor:

```
var reg = new RegExp('(\\b' + typedval + '\\b)', 'i');
```

Because the users can add RegExp special characters, it becomes a little tedious, but remains a requirement, to guard against those characters:

```
typedval = oAcF._sTypedChars.toLowerCase().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call/).
- [JavaScript regular expressions guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`Node.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Comment: How do you prevent breaking the regexp when input is a `+` or a `(` for example?

Comment: @Mouser: you have a point. I'll edit to add that, momentarily.

Comment: Mark: thank you, and it should go without saying that you're very welcome indeed :)